# Accordion in javascript is not calling function

Tags: javascript, accordion

Im working on Accordion in java script and it's failing to call function i.e, it's not opening the content of that button.

HTML

```
<div class="accwrapper">
<button class="accordion" type="button" onclick="open()">Section1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    Hithesh
  </p>
</div>
<button class="accordion" type="button">Section2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    fsdf
  </p>
</div>
<button class="accordion" type="button">Section3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    ffhhhh
  </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.open = function() {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i];
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

Why its not calling the open() function, and its navigating to home page

Comment: use `ng-click=open()` directive instead of `onclick `

Comment: its not navigating to home page, but its not working.@ShivKumarBaghel

Comment: is alert coming on click ?

Comment: why is `acc[i]` written on the first line of the for loop?

Comment: nooo.. i tried with alert, its not comming @ShivKumarBaghel

Comment: added my answer to check click. after that check your code it has lots of issues.

Comment: i tried like this [link](https://youtu.be/1bmYdvnyKrw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code snippet to check no need to `click` function. implemented with `ng-repeat` directive

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.accordion = {
     current: null
   };
 
   $scope.items = [
       { id: 1, content: 'Hithesh'},
       { id: 2, content: 'fsdf'},
       { id: 3, content: 'ffhhhh'},
     ];
   
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="accwrapper">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <button class="accordion" type="button" ng-click="accordion.current = item.id">Section1</button>
        <div class="panel" ng-show="accordion.current == item.id">
          <p>
            {{item.content}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes its working, i mean alert is showing. but its not opening the content, am i wrong in writting function to open the contents????? can u help in correct code for that?@Shiv Kumar Baghel

Comment: yes please have a look into your code. give time to it :)

Comment: okey... Thank you @Shiv Kumar Baghel...Can u help me with funtion for that, addEventListner and onClick is not working for me

Comment: updated code. please have a look. im using simple `ng-repeat` to create accordion like structure and show/hide on click. pls upvote if it solve your problem.

Comment: i cant upvote coz im less than 15 reputations and thank you for the solution